# rsync freezing/hanging/stopping after a couple of files

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux, transfer

I have this folder with 25,000 images (around 80MB total) and I want to transfer all of them to a server.

This is the command I am using:

```bsh
rsync -av -e 'ssh' ./pics/ user@132.456.789.10:~/pics/
```

The transfer freezes after a couple of files and when I stop the process, I get this error:

```bsh
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(644) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I know that it doesn't work because the server location doesn't have the images after freezing.

I tried running the command without the console output `-v`, but it still freezes.

What might be the problem?

Comment: If you ssh and do a command which produces 2-3 pages of text, does it work? If not, I would look at MTU sizes.
And second question, how do you know it is frozen?

Comment: @marosg I know it's frozen because I check what was transferred to the server and the files stay the same i.e. nothing is added. I don't know what MTU sizes are, I will check it out. I could use some advice tho.

Comment: easiest is to use `tracepath` command, it will show if mtu changes on the path. Another thing, on target server, have you checked the load? Maybe high wait%?

Comment: @marosg wtf, the transfer continues if I keep resizing the terminal??? If I stop, the transfer stops.

Comment: lol. cannot be, there must be something else going on

Comment: @marosg I am dead serious. I am using the Windows Ubuntu subsystem, so it might be a problem with the terminal just for this case. Super weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced this too.
Resizing the window to make things work is a real thing :-/
And this fixed things: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2138#issuecomment-393617253

To summarize the solution:
Open a new WSL (Ubuntu) window and run this script

`while killall -CHLD ssh; do sleep 0.1; done`

Comment: Holy shit, that really fixed it! Weird as fuck.